# Apple rejects our latest App

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

Our latest app was rejected by giving following reason

"when the user launches the app, a blank black screen is produced"

We had tested this many times and did not notice this issue. We tested again now, but it is working properly for us.

Can someone help us to find out the issue?

Comment: You tested on an actual device, right?

Comment: This problem usually (maybe also in your case) occours if you're doing something GUI-related in a background thread. Possibly at application startup to speed-up the process?

Comment: We have not done any GUI-Related in a background thread.. But we doing a background operation to download some data. This is not showing any blank screens also...

Comment: yes sure you can send which mail got from apple and source code of the Application we will help you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anyone can help you find this issue, My suggestion would be to follow up with the Review Team and try to obtain as much information as you can from them. Such as, what device was it tested on, what OS version and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the many woes of the app store process.
Make sure that you have tested your app not only on the simulator but also on a physical device. 
Secondly the issue might be that you have made some (false) assumptions about the data on the device, that you might have put there manually, but isn't handled when installing anew.

Therefore a plan of attack might be to remove the application complete from both device and simulator and try running them from a fresh install rather than on top of an already installed installation.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try to build and install your app from a clean state. You may not be seeing the same as the reviewer, because if you only "build&run" all the time, old files, which are not part of the final build, are still present on your device or in the simulator.

So clean the build folder, remove the app from your device, and try again. Also, check if you app can live without an internet connection.

Comment: Additionally, I'd suggest to install from iTunes with Ad-Hoc provisioning to be as close to a real install as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to discuss this directly with the Apple guys (Resolution Center).